# Process cannot read from the standard input in Swift

Tags: swift, macos, process, stdin, sudo

I'm trying to run a command with eleveated privileges by spawning `sudo` child process using [`Process`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/process):

```swift
let process = Process()
process.executableURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/usr/bin/sudo")
process.arguments = ["ls"]
try process.run()
process.waitUntilExit()
```

However, after compiling and running the progam above, I'm unable to enter the `sudo` password, and the process seems to hang.

Ater pressing the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> and then manually killing the process with `kill -9 %1`, I get the following:

```
% sudo: a password is required
```

Running `sudo` in non-interactive mode by adding the `-n` argument results in the following:

```
sudo: a password is required
```

However, when doing the same in Python (and other languages, I've tried Golang and Rust), `sudo` can read the input without problems:

```py
import subprocess

subprocess.run(["sudo", "ls"])
```

Answer (score 4):

This is likely happens because Swift's [`Process`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/process) uses [posix_spawn(2)](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man2/posix_spawn.2.html), which has no support for setting terminal process group TPGID (see [this](https://github.com/att/ast/issues/468) and [this](https://sourceware.org/pipermail/libc-alpha/2021-July/128606.html) for more details), at least on Darwin.

This effectively backgrounds the spawned process (in [job control](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Job-Control-Basics.html) terms) and causes it to be stopped after the child process tries to read from the terminal (which `sudo` does when trying to read your password).

This is best diagnosed with ps/top/htop utilities:

```
% ps xao pid,ppid,pgid,tpgid,state,comm | { head -1 ; grep sudo }
  PID  PPID  PGID TPGID STAT COMM
30061 29995 30061 29995 T    /usr/bin/sudo
30081 30073 30073 30073 S+   /usr/bin/sudo
```

The first process is started through Swift's `Process` and you can see that it had already been stopped (`T`) because it received SIGTTIN after trying to read from the terminal.

The second process is started through Python's [`subprocess` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) and has a correct `TPGID`.

An easy fix would be to call [tcsetpgrp(3)](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/tcsetpgrp.3.html) after `process.run()` as follows:

```
tcsetpgrp(STDIN_FILENO, process.processIdentifier)
```

We've done this workaround [in Tart](https://github.com/cirruslabs/tart/commit/2be5eedeb67359cd26e2974c1d10651fa2e21f92#diff-9f9e4d2490229fdc73c5a84329ecb30149cfd4ff3da3f4d39dc726279e19c51fR144-R146) and it works flawlessly.

Comment: [The Swift implementation of Foundation is indeed using posix_spawn in Process.run](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/main/Sources/Foundation/Process.swift#L960)